# What is the meaning of "reine Höhle" (in a proverb)

Tags: translation, proverb

What is the meaning of the expression "reine Höhle"? I guess it means "tranquility" or "peace" but I want to be sure.

I saw it in the [proverb](https://www.sprichwoerter.net/deutsche-sprichwoerter-und-redewendungen/s/schoene-seele-will-reine-hoehle.html): Schöne Seele will reine Höhle.

Comment: @marzipanherz No, it actually seems to be a proverb - but I don't get its meaning...

Comment: This seems to be *Mens sana in corpore sano*

Comment: Are you sure you do not mean "reine Hölle?" - "Das war die reine Hölle" is a very common everyday language (or slightly slang) expression for "This was a very bad or difficult situation."

Comment: This question cries for improvement by adding the context where this peculiar expression appears. (What you call context is not actually context, it is just a short phrase.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann pure hell? :)

Comment: Hi @Tom how are things? :)

Comment: A Google search on "Schöne Seele reine Höhle" finds surprisingly many results. With "Hölle", I am not able to find anything.

Comment: @tofro - you are right. In the right context it definitely makes sense. Your answer below is spot on.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Auch wenn die Wortgruppe _reine Hölle_ so grundsätzlich geläufig/gebräuchlich  ist - was genau wäre dann die Bedeutung des kompletten Sprichworts?

Comment: I think the current answers are off. Surely that proverb was conceived by one Tom Marvolo Riddle, who wanted the cave for [his soul](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffe_der_Harry-Potter-Romane#Horkrux) to stay clear of contamination. He certainly made sure to have lots of eager [servants](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begriffe_der_Harry-Potter-Romane#Inferius) in it who would take care of that...

Comment: @Marzipanherz  Aaaalso... wenn das Sprichwort hieße "Schöne Seele will *reine* Hölle", dann würde ich sagen, der Sprichwortsprecher will damit sagen: "Eine mental stabile und auf das Schöne im Leben orientierte Persönlichkeit wird auch in extrem ungemütlicher Umgebung versuchen, Ordnung und vor allem Sauberkeit um sich herum zu schaffen." - Aber dies ist natürlich jetzt nur eine Gedankenspielerei. So wie die Frage zunächst gestellt war, war ja noch nicht klar, dass es hier um ein Sprichwort ging. Das wurde erst durch Nachfrage und Nachbesserung klar.

Answer (score 12):

Although I have actually never heard this before (so I'd state it is not exactly a common idiom in German), I would say this seems to mean more or less the same thing as the old Latin

> [Mens sana in corpore sano](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mens_sana_in_corpore_sano)

As it literally means a fine soul wants to dwell in a clean cave - thus, in a figurative meaning essentially the same meaning.

You could ask what exactly a *cave* or *cavity* has to do with that proverb instead of *Körper* or even *Leib*? I would assume a rhyme (Seele <-> Höhle) always helps in a proverb, and *Höhle* has at least some notation of containment.

Comment: Ähm... [corpore](https://www.frag-caesar.de/lateinwoerterbuch/corporum-uebersetzung.html) ist der Ablativ von **Körper**, nicht Höhle.

Comment: @Takkat Sprichwörter brauchen manchmal ein Mindestmaß an Phantasie. Eine Tropfsteinhöhle, die man vorher schrubben soll, bevor man seine Seele reintut, ist bestimmt nicht gemeint.

Comment: @tofro Yep.Ist anscheinend schon alt? Siehe [Buch 1846](https://books.google.de/books?id=cAs-AAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA445&ots=HETGCUW3T8&dq=Sch%C3%B6ne%20Seele%20will%20reine%20H%C3%B6hle.&pg=PA446)

Comment: *Mens bella in caverna sana* also? Hm...

Comment: [This book](http://www.zeno.org/Wander-1867/A/Seele) links it with the danish proverb _En smuk siel vil have et smuk legem_ which translates back to _Eine schöne Seele will einen schönen Körper_, if I'm correct.

Comment: Nachdem *Höhle* nie die Bedeutung *Körper* hatte müßte man postulieren, dass irgendjemand irrtümlicherweise einmal die *Hülle* (kann man in der Bedeutung Hülle für die Seele durchaus akzeptieren) in eine *Höhle* verwandelt hätte... das finde ich ziemlich konstruiert. Phantasiebegabten reicht aber vielleicht eine solche Tiefe an etymologischer Forschung.

Comment: @Takat: Ich würde Höhle im Sinne von Wohnstätte als Analogie für den _Körper als Wohnstätte der Seele_ interpretieren :)

Comment: @Takkat Alleine schon die Begriffe *Bauchhöhle* oder *Mundhöhle* erlauben es durchaus, von Körperhöhlungen als einer Höhle zu sprechen. Hier scheint's mir aber wichtiger gewesen zu sein, dass es sich auf "Seele" reimt.

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Höhle als *Wohnstätte* finde ich prima, denn dann schließt sich der Kreis und es ist kein Körper mehr ;)

Comment: @Takkat Du darfst dann den Kreis noch mehr schließen und den Körper als *Wohnstätte* der Seele betrachten. Dann ist's wieder ein Körper.

Comment: @tofro Oha, den Reim hatte ich gar nicht bemerkt. Gut beobachtet!

Comment: @Takkat: Da Höhle sich auch nur schwach auf Seele reimt hätte man gleich "Hülle" nehmen können.

Comment: Angesichts dessen, dass das Sprichwort - wie man aus seiner Sammlungsgeschichte ableiten kann - vermutlich im bäuerlichen Umkreis in Gebrauch war, denke ich, dass eine Verwendung im Sinne von "Man soll sein Haus sauber halten" wahrscheinlicher ist als ein Philosophieren über die Koinzidenz von psychischer und physischer Gesundheit.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say 'reine Höhle' can be taken in a literal sense here, i.e. 'clean cave', meaning that a beautiful soul cannot have / does not want a messy home / environment.

This may be based on the saying that a chaotic room / house reflects the mental state of its owner, for which I'm currently lacking more specific sources other than having heard it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the facts collected collectively here in answers and comments, and adding some information from a 19th century source:

> Schöne Seele will reine Höhle

seems to be an old proverb. It is documented in Karl Simrock's [collection of proverbs published in 1846](https://books.google.de/books?id=cAs-AAAAIAAJ&lpg=PA445&ots=HETGCUW3T8&dq=Sch%C3%B6ne%20Seele%20will%20reine%20H%C3%B6hle.&pg=PA446) (as commenter LangLangC pointed out first) which again is a compilation of a number of earlier such collections, as its preface explains [Simrock 1846 p. IV]. Proverbs in this book are listed in alphabetical order based on one of the core words used in the proverbs.

Regarding the "Seele-Höhle" proverb itself one might add that it is **not in use any more** - therefore the struggle to interpret it visible here in the comments. I have not heard, read or otherwise met it even once in several decades of private and professional use of German.

One can even not be sure that the proverb was in *common* use at any time. Generally, the book of 1846 is the result of a number of earlier attempts of collecting proverbs that could be described as casting a fishing net and catching everything that people in even the remotest village have ready as everyday wisdom put into fixed phrases. What ever was found was recorded as a proverb, even if it was known only to a very tiny group of people.

For the meaning of "Schöne Seele will reine Höhle": there is no attempt of interpreting it in the 1846 collection. My guess is that is was used as an **amonition to keep one's house tidy**. If that's correct you could translate it to (rather prosaic) modern day German:

> Ein psychisch gesunder und normal sozialisierter Mensch achtet darauf, dass auch seine Umgebung einen ordentlichen Eindruck macht.

Or to express it the other way round with a proverb that is still in use:

> Wie der Herr, so's G'scherr.

The general idea of congruence of inner and outer order, inner and outer health, inner and outer beauty is of course nothing special German; it is a meme (if you like) that can be found in I suppose every culture on planet earth. (Would be interesting though to see what e.g. groups of people - once called "tribes" - living remotely in the djungle have in that respect.) I believe one could create a whole class of proverbs expressing this meme. This would include except of "Wie der Herr, so's Gscherr":

> Mens sana in corpore sano
>
> Ordnung ist das halbe Leben

(*List to be continued. I will add proverbs suggested in comments.*)

Another theory of the genesis of such a saying would be that it is a substitute proverb for the famous Latin "mens sana in corpore sano". I would find it plausible to assume that, in order to provide students with an easily memorable translation, some school teacher in the early 19th century came up with the (a bit tortured) translation "Schöne Seele will reine Höhle" where *Höhle* is used as a metaphora for the dwelling place of the mind, i.e. the body.

---

**Bibliography**

Simrock, Karl: Deutsche Sprichwörter. (= Die deutschen Volksbücher. Gesammelt und in ihrer ursprünglichen Echtheit wiederhergestellt von Karl Simrock. Fünfter Band.) Frankfurt am Main, 1846.

Comment: Als wahrscheinliche Quelle für das OP Zitat nehme ich aber stark an, dass der Hinterwalddörfler auf einer Lateinschule war und sich in Poetik+Humor versuchen wollte? Oder realistischer: weniger von einem Lehrer als aus dem Studentendeutsch, ein juveniler Juvenalist, vielleicht sogar aus burschenschaftlicher Deutschtümelei? Daher als Zeitraum von Sturm&Drang bis Willy2? Oh, caveat Spekulatius.

Comment: Btw die Dänischen Varianten sind interessant (cf. Marzipanherz) und dies hier auf [zeno](http://www.zeno.org/Eisler-1904/A/Schöne+Seele) wie auch andere Einträge drumrum dort. Und zur gegenwärtigen Verwendung [ein aktuelles Buch](https://books.google.de/books?id=X3dFDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT3303&ots=U3Vlq8PSa7&dq=%22Mens%20sana%20in%20corpore%20sano%22%20seele%20h%C3%B6hle&pg=PT3303) oder ein [Blog?](http://bloghuette.info/hoehlenfrieden/). Denk ja oft an Goethe und den Untertitel von Wilhelm Meister.